# autotools configure.ac error checking perl module

Tags: perl-module, autotools

In my configure.ac, I want to check in this `perl` module `exiftool` (http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-10.20/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod) exists as:

```
AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES( Image::ExifTool, ,)
```

But this is giving error:

```
./configure: line 4071: syntax error near unexpected token `Image::ExifTool,'
./configure: line 4071: `AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES( Image::ExifTool, ,)'
```

What is going wrong here?

For reference, here is my complete configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([mkbib], [0.1],[],[mkbib])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9.6 dist-bzip2 subdir-objects])
AM_PATH_PYTHON([3.0])
AM_PATH_GTK_3_0([3.4.0],,AC_MSG_ERROR([Gtk+ 3.0.0 or higher required.]))
AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES( Image::ExifTool, ,)

GLIB_GSETTINGS
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile 
                 data/Makefile
                 data/mkbib.desktop
                 data/icons/Makefile
                 data/icons/hicolor/Makefile
                 data/icons/hicolor/48x48/Makefile
                 data/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/Makefile
                 data/icons/hicolor/scalable/Makefile
                 data/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/Makefile
                 data/ui/Makefile
                 ])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Any one please?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES m4 macro available when you run autoconf.  That text should not appear in your configure script.  You'll need to install it from the autoconf archive.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a definition of `AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES` in your project. This comes from the [Autoconf archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_perl_modules.html), rather than base autoconf (thus the `AX_` prefix.) You probably want to download the `.m4` (and any of its dependencies) and add it to your `m4/` directory, then run something along the lines of `autoreconf -is -I m4`.

You can dig further into the external macro usage on my [Autotools MYthbuster](https://autotools.io/autoconf/macros.html) if you're interested, but the gist of it is that.

Comment: hi, 
While I was searching, I was landed in a different page of your complete blog, different from the page you have shown. This is quite clear. But, I have solved the problem using http://fossies.org/linux/pacpl/configure.ac, where m4's r put in aclocal/ dir, and I need to run aclocal once. Can you comment on this?

Comment: aclocal should be run by `autoreconf`, but you're using `m4_include` so you should not need aclocal for *that* macro (you may still need it for something else.) I would suggest setting up the right autoconf macros to tell it where to find the m4 files (whether it is `aclocal/` or `m4/` it doesn't really matter, I prefer the latter out of consistency) and just use `autoreconf`.